# register_taxonomy does not create user taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress

Trying to create a set of user taxonomies with no result. Error log is empty. The code works for custom post types, but when I set it to create user taxobomy- nothing happens. Not sure where this went wrong.

```
add_action( 'init', 'user_status_taxonomy' );
function user_status_taxonomy() {
 register_taxonomy(
    'profession', 'user',
     array(
        'public' => true,
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Professions' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Profession' ),
            'menu_name' => __( 'Professions' ),
            'search_items' => __( 'Search Professions' ),
            'popular_items' => __( 'Popular Professions' ),
            'all_items' => __( 'All Professions' ),
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Profession' ),
            'update_item' => __( 'Update Profession' ),
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Profession' ),
            'new_item_name' => __( 'New Profession Name' ),
            'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate professions with commas' ),
            'add_or_remove_items' => __( 'Add or remove professions' ),
            'choose_from_most_used' => __( 'Choose from the most popular professions' ),
        )
    )
);
}
```

Comment: You have a typo "label" should be "labels"

Comment: changed it. Still nothing

Comment: Also, will need to add it to the admin menu using the admin_menu hook, users don't have categories by default. Posts do, this is why you will need to create the category page manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add the category page to the admin menu. The function above is simply registering the taxonomy. Not displaying it anywhere until its called upon.

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'add_user_categories_to_admin' );

function add_user_categories_to_admin() {
    $taxonomy = get_taxonomy('profession');
    add_users_page(
        esc_attr( $taxonomy->labels->menu_name ),//The Page Title
        esc_attr( $taxonomy->labels->menu_name ),//The Menu Title
        $taxonomy->cap->manage_terms, // Taxonomy Capabilities
        'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=' . $taxonomy->name // The Slug
    );
}
```

Comment: Yep. That's it. Thank you!